# Setting Up Nutch 2.2

Tags: maven, ant, solr, nutch

I am trying to set-up Nutch 2.2.
When I run the `ant runtime` command to build the project it fails to build with:

```
Server access Error: Connection refused..........
```

Which is followed by the maven repositories of the files it cannot download.

There is a proxy server set-up that often will not allow me to download certain things and I fear this is the problem here.

Is there any other way of setting this up?

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure the proxy for ant, so in console, before `ant runtime`, you can configure ant options like:

```
export ANT_OPTS='-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttp.proxyPort=8080 -Dhttp.proxyUser=user -Dhttp.proxyPassword=password -Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy -Dhttps.proxyPort=8080'
```

If that is not enough, maybe will need to configure `~/.m2/settings.xml` adding (something like):

```
<proxies>
    <proxy>
        <id>proxyId</id>
        <active>true</active>
        <protocol>http</protocol>
        <username>user</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <host>proxy</host>
        <port>8080</port>
        <nonProxyHosts>localhost|127.0.0.1</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>   
</proxies>
```

Comment: If I do not have the permissions for the proxy is there an alternative?

Comment: I guess nothing, then. I don't know any other way :(